# Renaming variable column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

so here is a data frame

```
a<-data.frame(Brand=c("X","Y","Z","d"),Month=1:4,TRP_A=6:9,TRP_B=7:10,TRP_C=10:7)
```

In custom function I will need to select one of TRP_A,TRP_B or TRP_C and this will be parameter TRP in function

So let's say I call the function down and as parameter TRP I enter 5 so column TRP_C will be chosen. But it will be named as TRP_C and I need to refer it further e.g. if I want to sum total of the column.

I need to rename TRP_C to general name e.g Target because next time I mights use TPR_B or so... But I don't know how to do it because rename function requires to pass origin name.

```
    aff<-function(brand,TRP) {

      a<-a%>%select(Brand,Month,TRP)

      total<-a%>%summarise(total=sum(TRP))
      total
    }

aff("X",5)
```

Comment: The `brand` and `Brand` in your function is different.  Are you looking for a function that implements this `a %>% select(Brand, Month, 5) %>% rename(TRP=TRP_C) %>% summarise(total=sum(TRP))`

Comment: Or do we need to `filter` the 'Brand' rows based on `brand' value and then get the `sum(TRP)`

Comment: There will be lot of things going on more variable . It's like your first option after selecting columns I want to rename whichever TRP columns is selected to general name which will be reffered to further

Comment: May be `aff <- function(brand, TRP1){
 a %>% filter(Brand==brand) %>% select(Brand, Month, TRP1) %>% setNames(., c('Brand', 'Month', 'TRP')) %>% summarise(Total=sum(TRP))

}`

Comment: Thanks Akrun it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 aff <- function(brand, TRP1){ 
        a %>%
         filter(Brand==brand) %>%
         select(Brand, Month, TRP1) %>% 
         setNames(., c('Brand', 'Month', 'TRP')) %>% 
         summarise(Total=sum(TRP)) }
```

Or we can change the `setNames` line to

```
aff <- function(brand, TRP1){ 
              a %>%
              filter(Brand==brand) %>%
              select(Brand, Month, TRP1) %>% 
              setNames(., sub('\\_.*', '', names(.))) %>%
              summarise(Total = sum(TRP))}
```