# Renaming a Summarised Column inside Redshift dplyr operations

Tags: r, dplyr, amazon-redshift, dbplyr

I am using dplyr to do certain operations in Redshift so I don't load the data in memory.

```
data <- tbl(conn, "customers") %>%
  filter(age >= 18)
subset <- data %>% 
  filter(eye_color != "brown") %>%
  group_by(gender, method, age, region) %>% 
  summarise(sum(purchases)) %>%  # will create a column called sum(purchases)
  full_join(data, by=c("region", "age", "method"))
```

Right now when I look at the resulting dataframe, I will see a column called `sum(purchases)` and I want to rename it to `purchases` which will create the columns, `purchase.x` and `purchase.y` after the merge.

Most of the renaming that I've [read](https://blog.exploratory.io/selecting-columns-809bdd1ef615) so far are dealing with dataframes that are in memory rather than dataframes that are lazily evaluated with dbplyr. I have tried using `rename`, `rename_`, `rename_at` as well as different variations of `select`. I have also tried strategies laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45076971/changing-names-of-resulting-variables-in-custom-dplyr-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626682/renaming-variable-column-in-r) but no luck

Is there a way to rename the `sum(purchases)`. The only other option I have is to load the dataframe in memory at a certain step

```
data <- tbl(conn, "customers") %>%
  filter(age >= 18)
subset <- data %>% 
  filter(eye_color != "brown") %>%
  group_by(gender, method, age, region) %>% 
  summarise(sum(purchases)) %>% 
loaded <- as.data.frame(subset)
# do some join here but in memory and not in Redshift
# full_join(data, by=c("region", "age", "method"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign names in `summarise`.  I don't have your data so I can't triple-check, but I've used this in my own code before when calling `summarise(n())`.  Something like...

```
summarise(your_column_name = sum(purchases))
```

You can also pass it a column name with spaces, you just have to use backticks

```
summarise(`your column name` = sum(purchases))
```